# NSInvalidArgumentException/copyWithZone exception with NSMutableDictionary

Tags: iphone

I have a class that I'm encapsulating ABRecordID with and when it's used as a key to add to an NSMutableDictionary, I get the run-time exception:

> "NSInvalidArgumentException: ***
>   -[MyRecordId copyWithZone:]: unrecognized selector sent to
>   instance"

MyRecordId declared as:

```
@interface MyRecordId : NSObject {
    ABRecordID abRecordId;
}

-(id)initWithId:(ABRecordID)anABRecordId;
@property (nonatomic) ABRecordID abRecordId;

@end
```

Adding to dictionary:

```
NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
MyRecordId *recordId = [[MyRecordId alloc] initWithId:anABRecordId];
[dict setObject:@"hello" forKey:recordId];
```

The last line causes the exception.. I know that you can't store non-object types as keys for a dictionary but I thought that wrapping it up in NSObject derived class would make it okay.

Am I not supposed to store ABRecordID in other objects? Should I be doing something else?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use NSNumber to store the ABRecordID in an Obj-C class:

```
[dict setObject:@"hello" forKey:[NSNumber numberWithInt:recordId]];
```

to obtain the recordId again, do:

```
recordId = [[dict objectForKey:@"hello"] intValue];
```

Answer (score 6):

NSDictionary keys need to implement the NSCopying protocol. That's why it's telling you your object doesn't respond to `copyWithZone:`.

Answer (score 6):

The class of the object you use as a key value should conform to the `NSCopying` protocol.
Basically it should implement the `copyWithZone:` method.

Instead of using your own class to wrap your non-object variable in, you should use `NSValue` class, which is designed for this purpose and supports the `NSCopying` protocol.

Comment: I didn't know that NSValue was best suited for this purpose. Which initializer would I use to constructing it with 'ABRecordID'?

Comment: I'm going with 'NSValue valueWithNonretainedObject' personally, should work for you. Just keep in mind that it wont retain your object for you of course...

Answer (score 1):

For the coding challenged like me, make sure the arguments to setObject are the right way around.  I just wasted hours on this error before I noticed I had them reversed!

Comment: sweet christ, this was precisely my problem too, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can also use NSNumber for this purpose as it inherits from NSValue.

Answer (score 0):

Diederik is on the right path, but given the type of `ABRecordID`, I'd recommend using `NSNumber` (an `NSValue` subclass). You'd use `-initWithInt:` for `ABRecordID` which is an `int32_t`.